# Parent div won't adjust to child div with grid display

Tags: html, css

Like in the title, I want to build a simple website, but I can't make parent div adjust to the content inside. If there is any content, it works great, but if I make child div `display: grid` like I want, parent div height is just `100vh`, but no more, even if grid items are overflowing down. Here is the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  background: grey;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  background: turquoise;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 40%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 40%);
  column-gap: 5rem;
  row-gap: 5rem;
}

.content-object {
  background: url("Project4.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container one">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
    <div class="content-object"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container two">

</div>
```

Comment: It's because background image isn't considered as "content". unless you have actual content or give your child elements specific height and width, it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 40%);
```

40% is too big for the rows. Use px instead.

also

```
row-gap: 5rem;
```

is too much.

Here is a demo [codepen link](https://codepen.io/just-trying-to-be-a-coder/pen/eYeYrqO)

I have also added padding top and bottom on the container.